# How to get The position of a sprite automatically in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm really new to unity and I'm trying to do a card game , And i get faced with the problem of coordinates . I'm trying to get the position of a the touch and make the sprite move for a specific position in the screen . Here is the my workaround script in c#:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CardMovement : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Rect recta = new Rect (-4.71f,-3.98f,4.52f,6.8f);

    Touch To = new Touch ();

    Camera C = GetComponent<Camera>();

    Vector3 p = new Vector3 ();

    p = C.ScreenToWorldPoint (To.position);

    if (recta.Contains(p)== true){

        transform.Translate(0.79f,-1.13f,0f);

    }


}
}
```

The problem is that i can't get it to move to that specific position .is it because of the coordinates that aren't matching ? and is there a way to get the coordinates of the sprite directly without typing them ?thanks for help ;)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Touch the card and then it moves to an specific point in the screen?

I'm not sure how you are trying to get this done because you can use new UI system, Sprites, Planes, everything works for a 2D perspective so it will be really helpfull if you clarify a little bit more. As far as I can see, you are trying to use a 3D view to translate the card.

I recomend you to view this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cdNMpsIkm4) it's a little noisy at the start so be careful

Comment: You are looking for the position of an object? The most basic would be gameObject.transform.position; No?

Comment: Sorry for being late to answer , What i want to do is to detect when the user touchs the area where the sprite lies and in response of that  it will move to a specific position that i want .

Comment: @Salvador i used 3D dimension because the  method Camera.screenTOViewportpoint recommands a 3D vector .thanks for help

Comment: @Andromelus Iwill try that .thanks for help

Comment: So... What I suggest is this: You need to use a [raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) to detect the card you are touching (the last example should work), then for that card I would apply a position update throught a [Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) so the transition looks smooth and nice:

Card.T.Position = Lerp(Card.ActualPos, FinalPos, t);

It's much like @Grelak suggest

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is detect the position where the user is tapping against a surface/zone, this object must have a collider and you should use a Raycast to detect where is the collision.

[Moving an Agent to a Position Clicked by the Mouse](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-MoveToClickPoint.html)

In this example they use the navmesh from unity but you don't have to, the information you are looking for is in **hit.point**

Answer (score 0):

I managed to move the card to the position I wanted ( not exactly ) And used another code that i built myself , your proposition I didn't use because I didn't understand or i guess it's using 3D script ( If i'm wrong please correct me ) so here is the updated version of my code :

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

public class CardMovement : MonoBehaviour {
public RectTransform rectangle;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    rectangle = GetComponent<RectTransform> ();


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (rectangle.rect.Contains (Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition)){

        Vector2 V = new Vector2 (0.125f, 0.125f);

        transform.position = V;


    }


}
}
```

Now the main problems that i face :

- the (0.125,0.125) that i used for the 2D vector gave me a place in the middle of the screen while it should be as i think for (0.5,0.5) vector (the last vector gave me a position of the card outside the screen  ) .
- When I used `Camera.ScreenToWorldpoint` or `Camera.ScreenToViewportpoint` the card didn't respond to the touch ( i guess it a problem of coordinates )

**NOW THE MAIN QUESTION** : WHAT IS THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THESE COORDINATES : World coordinates , screen coordinates and view port coordinates . I didn't find an explanation in the unity manual .

Thanks for help :) .